# TreeView and SiteMap: How to add a line break?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, sitemap, line-breaks

my sitemap is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/Default.aspx" title="Administration"  description="">
   <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/Overview.aspx" title="Übersicht"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/UserOverview.aspx" title="Benutzer"  description="">
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/CompanyOverview.aspx" title="Firmen"  description="">
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/OrganisationOverview.aspx" title="Organisationen"  description="">
  </siteMapNode>
 </siteMapNode>
  <!-- LINE BREAK SHOULD BE HERE -->
 <siteMapNode url="~/Admin/Settings.aspx"  title="Einstellungen"   description="">

  </siteMapNode>
 </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

I have a TreeView binded on it with a SiteMapDataSource.

Here is it how it looks like: http://www.imgimg.de/bild_18a9b0128PNG.png.html

How I get a Linebreak in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1041055.aspx), you can include the following to get a `<hr />` tag but you'll have to disable postback for this item.

```
<siteMapNode title="&lt;hr /&gt;"  description="separator" url=""/>
```